# How do you solve $5^n = 6n$, for example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

With graphing calc, you find intersection.
but how do you algebraically solve $5^n = 6n$, for example?
Log both sides not obvious

Comment: You don't, or at least, you don't necessarily without the use of non-elementary functions such as the [lambert-w function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), approximations, or luck in spotting a solution with inspection.  Just because a question is easy to write does not make it easy to answer.  Not all easy to write equations have simple solutions.

Comment: Do you mean for $n\in\Bbb R$ or for, say, $n\in\Bbb N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These kinds of problems require the Lambert W function to solve:
$$5^n=e^{n\ln5}=6n$$
$$-\frac{\ln5}6=(-\ln5)ne^{(-\ln5)n}$$
$$W\left(-\frac{\ln5}6\right)=(-\ln5)n$$
$$n=\frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln5}6\right)}{-\ln5}$$
One real solution is $0.2487\dots$ and the other is $1.25383\dots$